# Java binary tree

Tags: java

Здравствуйте,подскажите,как сделать копию связанного списка? Работаю с деревом целых чисел. Создала preorder,postorder и inorder iteratory. Преордер работает хорошо,потом долго не могла понять ,почему не работает инордер. Потом до меня дошло,что Преордер изменил начальный объект. Как сделать копию, но не указателя на дерево, а копию самого дерева. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А можно код?

Comment: Итератор не должен менять исходный контейнер (ваше дерево) в процессе обхода.

Comment: Russtam, вот класс ,представляющий узел
http://pastebin.com/vumZCYYH
и вот клас preOrder iterator:
http://pastebin.com/3kevNyaV

Comment: я понимаю. проблема в том,что к каждому узлу списка я добавила переменную available,которая сообщает можно ли в него входить. она и поменялась и я не знаю, что сделать,чтобы это исправить. чтобы,допустим,после прохождения преИтератором,все перепенные available всех узлов переставились на true для inorder и postorder итераторов

Comment: evgeniya, вот a_gura правильно сказал(а) что не надо менять контейнер. Либо как вариант, новый итератор создавать после изменений. Т.е. создали первый итератор, поработали, создали второй итератор, поработали, создали третий и т.д.

Comment: проверяет система git,и создает сразу три итератора.
а можно,по вашему мнению,написать итератор без переменной доступа?

Comment: или как просто сделать пометку на узле,что утератор там уже был и туда возвращаться не стоит,если вы понимаете о чем я

Comment: Как-то не очень понял при чем тут git. А вообще само дерево не должно содержать инфы для итераторов или меняться при проходе по итераторам.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, надо убрать у узла available. А в конструкторах итераторов полностью формировать список обхода (сохранить его в стек или в простой список) и потом просто его использовать в next() и hasNext().